# combine URL together and display on one GUI android,java

Tags: java, android, weather, psi

I would like to ask , 
how to I combine 2 url together and display it out?
For example
I would like to take the weather info from Yahoo Weather (http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1062617&u=c)
and
PSI details from NEA( http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml) 
and display both data out in one GUI.

Thanks

Comment: y dont u use 2 webview in single xml

Comment: Both are RSS feed and I've managed to retrieve both data.
Just that both of them are on different XML layout

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? If so, share your attempt and tell us why it doesn't work.

Comment: @mthmulders I've yet to try out myself, just seeking for ideas on how do I combine it

Comment: @Stacks28 hi, thanks. I will give it a try.. But can I just combine both code togehter?

Comment: i think fragment will work

Comment: Okay, I will let  you know after i tried it. Thanks